# Checkbox insert to database from VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to insert a checkbox value into a SQL Server database but it does not work. May I know how to insert that value into a SQL Server database?

This is my code:

```vb
Dim serUpdate As string

Try sConn.Open
    If checkbox.Checked = True Then
       serUpdate = "INSERT INTO xxxx(checkbox) VALUES ('Y')"
End If

sCmd.CommandText = serUpdate
sCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Catch ex As Exception
    Response.write(ex)

Finally

    sConn.Close()

End Try
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Does it error? Does it give unexpected behaviour? Becomes sentient? Help us help you.

Comment: Boolean values are represented by an integer usually where 0 = false and <> 0 true

Comment: I would, personally, use a `bit` in SQL Server for a boolean, @G3nt_M3caj .

Comment: @Larnu SQL Server BIT data type is an integer data type that can take a value of 0, 1, or NULL isn't it?   :)

Comment: Hi @Larnu , thank your reply, checkbox cannot insert to the database, no error pop up. db table show 'null'

Comment: Hi @G3ny_M3caj , thank your reply, may i know that need to change checkbox.Checked <> 0?

Comment: No, @G3nt_M3caj , it is not. It does not behave the same as a `int`.

Comment: @Larnu may be I'm wrong but regard to the guide it is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @iamnew If you are working in SQL Server and your data type is a bit or boolean you have to write as value 0 for false and -1 for true or literal strings “True” for true and “False” for false.

Comment: It's *stored* as a integer value, but it does not act like an int, @G3nt_M3caj : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cccbf8f3db7b9eff036a90e1af5b0ca1).

Comment: Hi @G3nt_M3caj , my data type is bit and checkbox.Checked = True ,but not not work.. do you have any advise? thanks

Comment: @larnu Yes, nothing is new about what you showing, but 'True' is converted in int and 'Y' isn't. Was that my context

Comment: @iamnew Change this  ..... values ('Y') in ....values (-1) or ...values ('True')

Comment: Hi @G3nt_M3caj, you means INSERT INTO xxxxx (checkbox) values ('Y')?

Comment: @iamnew :) Yes, you have to change your query in:  INSERT INTO xxxxx (checkbox) values (-1) or  INSERT INTO xxxxx (checkbox) values ('True')

Comment: Hi @G3nt_M3caj, /3\ still not work, cannot insert to ms db table....

Comment: @iamnew You have to debug inserting you code inside a try catch block. It’s possible you have indexes/unique keys that might duplicated by inserting one field on your table without updating those keys/indexes properly.

Comment: *"my data type is bit"*. Then why on Earth are you trying to save the text value `"Y"` the that column? You're taking something very simple and making it hard. If you want to store Boolean data in SQL Server then use the `bit` data type. The `Checked` property of a `CheckBox` is type `Boolean` so that's what you save. There's no `If` statement. Just save the `Checked` property value.

Comment: Hi @G3nt_M3caj, i have using try catch but not message show up/3\

Comment: @Hi Jmcihineey, thank your reply, you means no need use if statement for checking? thanks

Comment: Either use `VALUES(1)` because `bit` is an actual number of 0 or 1. Or you can pass in the value as a parameter `VALUES(@checkBoxValue)` and `sCmd.Parameters.Add("@checkBoxValue", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = checkbox.Checked`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (MyBitColumn) VALUES (@MyBitColumn)", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@MyBitColumn", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = myCheckBox.Checked
    connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Done!